# signed to unsigned casting

Tags: c++, types, unsigned, signed

look at this code:

```
void main ()
{
int i = -1;
unsigned u = 1;

cout << u + i;
}
```

the addition of the u (unsigned) and i (signed), so i must be converted to the unsigned type, so it should be interpreted ( (2 ^ 32) - 1 ) and the expression should change from:
-1 + 1 to ( (2 ^ 32) - 1 ) + 1 but when i run the code it results to 0
why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-1` in an unsigned representation of the **largest possible** number unsigned can hold (`UINT_MAX`).

Adding 1 to this wraps over due to the properties of `unsigned`, thus equaling 0.

Answer (score 1):

(unsigned) -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF. 1 + 0xFFFFFFFF  = 0x100000000 which overflows the int, and results in 0.